# Is it possible to completely strace a script from the time of creation? How?

Tags: strace

Let's suppose I want to hook strace to a program to capture which files it writes to. I need an existing PID for that. If I hook up strace, by that point the script might already have written files, which I'll miss. Classic race condition. What I do now is trying to make another program that runs the original script which does nothing but `sleep 1` before the command is ran, so that I get the full strace. This feels like a bad thing to do. And performance issues come to play if running a lot of scripts. But I can't hook up strace without an existing PID. Or?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the script with a wrapper that runs `strace` that in turn launches the original script. This might involve

```
mv yourscript /somewhere/else/yourscript
```

and then `yourscript` becomes

```
#!/bin/sh
OUTPUT_TO=`mktemp /tmp/yourscript.$$.XXXXXXXXXX` || exit 1
exec strace -o $OUTPUT_TO ... /somewhere/else/yourscript "$@"
```

where `...` is whatever other `strace` arguments you need.

As an alternative, consider `sysdig`, as it can trace by filename or username without the need for a process ID or wrapper script:

```
sysdig -p '%fd.name' proc.name contains yourscript
```